# Fixed Header with solid bg color and transparent bg logo

Tags: html, css, transparency

Just after a bit of CSS help please.
I need to develop this header based on a PSD design, but no idea where to start with it.
It's a fixed header, full width and 125px high with white background. Behind it will be a 500px high slider. And the site's logo will be within 1000px centered wrapper, has a transparent background so that the slider image shows through.
Here is a capture of the design:

[image: screen capture]

Any ideas how this can be done please?

Comment: Couldn't you just use the regular logo image, then give it a thick solid white border then completely round the radius? And instead of making one full block div just divide it enough to allow the picture to see the background.

Comment: Possible, I could have the 1000px wrapper with div of "headleft" having logo image as bg image, and div of "headright" to fill the rest of the width, but then what fills the space either side of the wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**
I would create two divs. One with the logo with no background color and the other with the background color. Take a look at the code below. *Make sure* when you change the width of header-left that you update it in header-right.

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="header-left logo"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo" /></div>
    <div class="header-right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}

.header-left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 125px; 
}

.header-left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
    height: 125px; 
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

**Original:**
I would create PNG that has the logo transparent in the middle with 1000px on the left and right that was white and use the image as a background that was centered horizontally. Since it's just white it shouldn't be that big of a file.

Comment: I considered this as it seems to be the simplest solution but the client ideally wanted this offset to the left, on the left edge of the 1000px centred column.

Comment: @Adrian, I misunderstood you originally. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok that would work for within the 1000px wrapper, but .header would have to have white background to go to both edges of screen (full width) and then the logo would no longer be transparent.

Comment: In that case go back to my original idea but make the starting image 1000px wide and left align the logo where you want it. Then add an even amount of space on the left and right, say like 1000px and center it as a background image and it will be in the right place.

Comment: That seems to have worked, and when I restyle to make the site responsive once developed, if I want to make the wrapper 800px for example, I can just resize the original BG image from 3000px wide to 2400px and this should still have the same effect, right?